# Connect Azure VPS to different public database server

Tags: sql, database, azure, vps

I am newbie with Azure and i and have an Azure VPS. I have an error with my Azure VPS, i cannot connect from this VPS to different sql database server. I cannot connect from both my ASP.NET App and SQL Server Management. The error is The Network path is not found.

[The error i get from SQL Server Management install on my VPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGNpZ.jpg)

I can connect very well to this Database server from my computer, or any other compute.

[My Azure VPS EndPoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkKBZ.jpg)

Any idea to solve the problem? Thanks all

Comment: Are you connecting from other servers within your DB server firewall? Have you ensure the Azure IP addresses are OK on your db server's firewall (or whatever firewall protects your db server)

Comment: Thank for your comment. It just shared hosting database, and don't have any firewall block.

Comment: Are you sure? I couldn't connect to it from here.

Comment: I test with Azure local Database service, it work ok, but it cannot connect with remote database.

Comment: email me adamt at  microsoft.com